# SFP+ Cable From Uplink Port to SFP+ 10Gb NIC

Tags: switch, 10gbethernet, sfp

I have a specific question about using a [this 2m passive SFP+ cable](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B00B3T6BFU) to connect the 10Gb uplink port on a switch to a NIC in a server.

**Switch:** [Netgear GS752TXS](http://www.newegg.com/Product/Product.aspx?Item=N82E16833122436)

**Server NIC:** [HP NC522SFP](http://h18000.www1.hp.com/products/servers/networking/nc522sfp/index.html)

I'm fairly confident that the switch and server NIC are fine, but can I use that cable to connect a 10Gb uplink port to an SFP+ NIC and achieve 10Gbps results? I've read [this question](https://serverfault.com/questions/328621/can-switch-sfp-sfp-uplink-ports-connect-to-a-sfp-sfp-nic-and-how) and [this question](https://serverfault.com/questions/215934/please-demystify-the-10gb-ethernet-interfaces-cables), but my $5000 project depends on this working and I would like an expert's advice before I spend the $$.Those three things are all I need, correct? No transcievers, since I am straight sfp to sfp?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: indeed, that's the purpose of direct attach cables.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, you can do this in theory.

Keep your receipts because not all DAC cables work with every NIC/switch combination. It's best to use the cables that are known-good according to the switch manufacturer, though.

Comment: Thank you for your help - I made the purchase and now am waiting for everything to get here.